# Error during deployment on server

Tags: c#, activereports

Project runs fine on my local machine, but when I deploy on server I get this problem regarding active report, any help will be appreciated.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ActiveReports.PdfExport, Version=6.1.2814.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 52:          Line 53:
>   --> Line 54:
>    Line 55:
>    Line 56:

Comment: Well the error is pretty self explanatory.  Your missing an ActiveReports dll.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that either ActiveReports.PdfExport dll is missing from the server or it is of a different version. Please make sure the version is the same and that its CopyLocal property is set to true and is copied to the deployment server.

Comment: thanks i fixed it , you were right version on server is different to version on my local PC